# Making a bot with discord.js, how to make my bot detect a certain phrase?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm making a bot that will ping me if a certain phrase gets said in my discord. Currently I am using

```
if(message.content.toLowerCase() === 'word')
```

How can I make it so it will detect "word" in any sentence? New to coding so I just followed a guide and after a few hours I couldn't figure it out. I only got it to ping me if only "word" was said and nothing else.

Comment: regex is your friend.

Comment: So is `includes()`. Like `if (message.content.toLowerCase().includes('word'))`. Next time you should [do some research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) first...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check whether a string contains a substring in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789945/how-to-check-whether-a-string-contains-a-substring-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

A simplistic solution is:

```js
function contains(content, word) {
    return (content.toLowerCase().indexOf('word') >= 0);
}

console.log(contains("This is the word!")); //true
console.log(contains("This is WordPress")); //true
console.log(contains("Something")); //false
```

As you can see, the second example is incorrect, because WordPress semantically differs from `word`. So, if it's not enough to find the word, but we want to isolate it as well, then we can do something like this:

```js
function contains(content, word) {
    let pattern = new RegExp("[^a-z]" + word + "[^a-z]");
    return (pattern.test(content.toLowerCase()));
}

console.log(contains("This is the word!", "word")); //true
console.log(contains("This is WordPress", "word")); //true
console.log(contains("Something", "word")); //false
```

In this second example, I prepend and append `[^a-z]`, which means "not a letter"